# How to create directshow filter for Expression Encoder 4? or work with GRF

Tags: c#, expression, directshow.net

I have a digital tuner for cable , and i need to capture it with expression encoder the graph looks like in the picture : [image]

My problem is that i'm not that good with c++ i know a little bit of c# and from what i understood i'm supposed either to create a directshow filter for expression encoder either to create a graph and pass it to expression encoder . I don't know how to do neither of them.

Anyone have any advices? over-all i'm a verry fast learner and good with c# but thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression Encoder works with available video capture devices, which are capable to deliver video stream, typically in frames and and compressed, such as being capture by web camera.

You, on the contrary, build a chain of filters to produce a video stream. It is not a device and instead it is a video stream generated by software. Expression Encoder is not flexible to take such feed.

There is no easy way to connect the two. A typical approach is to create a virtual device that wraps the custom filter graph (that you provided) and exposes video stream as it it is a capture device. Making such virtual device registered and available to applications, you have an option to select and use it from Expression Encoder.

This kind of implementation would require you to write at least parts of code in C++ because the underlying APIs are all native.